# Required Field Issue with SharePoint 2010 December 2013 CU

Tags: 2010, javascript

I installed SP2 a couple of weeks ago to fix the issues with my XSLT Compiles timing oot (Which was a Bug introduced in SP1). Things seemed fine, but then a few days later we noticed that workflows with required Fields were stuck in the 'Starting' Status.  This was a known issue with SP2 and was supposed to be fixed in subsequent CU's.

So I applied the December 2013 CU. The 2013 CU changes the Titles of all Required Fields to be 'FieldName Required Field' . ( I knew this was happening in 2013, I did NOT know they were doing it to 2010). So this broke all my javascript that was looking for fields by their title.

My Question is : Is there a way to turn off this 'Feature' for SP 2010 on premises?

BTW, I am getting around this for the time being by inserting this at the beginning of all my javascript Code:

```
// THIS IS A HACK
// DEC2010 CU of SP2010 changes the Title of all Require Fields to 'Fieldname Required Field'
// This Hack removes the 'Required Field' text  from the title
$("select[Title$=' Required Field']").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("Title", $(this).attr("Title").split(" Required Field")[0]);
});
$("input[Title$=' Required Field']").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("Title", $(this).attr("Title").split(" Required Field")[0]);
});
```

enter code here